# Why doesn't this conditional insertion work in my Azure YML pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

**Question:** What is wrong with the syntax/logic/reasoning in the provided code sample and what must I do to get this type of logic to work?

**Expected Behavior:** If `Is Enabled` evaluates to `true`, set `bar` to the value of `LIB-ALT-BAR` from the Azure Key Vault; otherwise, set it to `LIB-BAR` from the Azure Key Vault.

**Actual Behavior:** `bar` always evaluates to the value of `LIB-BAR`.

**What I have tried:**

1. Moving the expression further down into the template pipeline flow.
2. Using a different parameter to determine when to use a different value.
3. As a sanity check, removing and then adding quotes to operands.
4. Implemented a PowerShell solution that determined whether to set the value of bar and what to set it to based on a number of other, more specialized criteria.

**Minimum Reproducible Example:** The YML below represents a minimum reproducible example of the issue we're running into. It is taken from an `azure-pipelines.yml file`.

```
parameters:
  - name: isEnabled
    type: boolean
    displayName: Is Enabled
    default: false

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: yamltemplates
      type: git
      name: 'Templates/foobarbaz.devops.yamltemplates'

stages:
  - template: foo/templates/my-template.yml@yamltemplates
    parameters:
      isEnabled: ${{ parameters.isEnabled }}

      ${{ if eq( parameters.isEnabled, true ) }}:
        bar: "$(LIB-ALT-BAR)"
      ${{ else }}:
        bar: "$(LIB-BAR)"
```

Comment: Did you try `eq(parameters.isEnabled, 'true')`? Although the way you wrote it *should* work, I've never had good luck with comparing boolean values in Azure Pipelines without first coercing them to string types.

Comment: Nope, haven't tried that yet. I've got tons of other code that just uses `true` that works just fine, but I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml is correct.

The parameter `isEnabled` is `boolean` type, and it has `false` for the default value.

You need to tick 'is Enabled' option when you run the pipeline, then it will be evaluated as `true`.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mike Hofer, could you please let me know if it works for you? Thanks.